# Generate Random Mathematical Functions

Tags: function, math, random

This is kind of a weird question, and might not be entirely appropriate for Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find anything about it online, so here it is...

Is there a way (or what is the best way) to generate random mathematical functions?  By this I don't mean that I want a function that generates a random number (line an RNG), but rather I want to dynamically create some function which which maps one or more real inputs from a domain to a single output using some mutate-able rules.

For example, in the simplest case, I could just generate a function of the form `f(x1,x2) -> Y` by applying a random operator to x1 and x2.  For example f could be:

```
   f = x1 + x2
or f = x1 - x2
or f = x1 * x2
etc...
```

However, I would like to be able to include more complex formulas including trigonometry, power functions, pseudorandom constants, possibly some calculus functions, etc...  Obviously, I cant just concatenate different chunks in a completely random way, since these functions always need to always have valid syntax.

This isn't for anything crypto-related so it doesnt have to be perfect, but the more entropy the better.  It would also be great if there is an easy way to keep track of what operations are being preformed and mutate them.

I'm not sure if anyone has any insights on this, or if it even made sense, but thank you anyway

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: This is not a very precisely stated question. What do you mean by "generate a function"? Do you mean just to display the function as text? Or generate code that executes the function? Do you know what operations you want to limit your generation to (e.g., does it include transcendental functions, or just 4 operations +, -, *, /)? One approach would be to write a parse tree generator, then translate the parse tree into an expression. The parse tree generator would apply the randomness at each node in the tree.

Comment: You need constraints (especially on depth, or generation may never terminate) when constructing a generator of this sort or else you may well end up with terms such as (just as an example): `gamma(sqrt(gamma(sqrt(gamma(sqrt(sin(x + sqrt((gamma(sqrt(x))))))))))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.  What I ended up doing was something along the lines of a parse tree, recursively generating new nodes with 2, 1, or 0 children (for binary or unary operators or constants).  You could cap depth by checking Node.getDepth().  Below is some JavaScript code showing this process.  I'm not sure how useful it will be but it works pretty much how I had envisioned.

```js
'use strict';

var print = console.log;

function randint(a, b) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * (b + 1 - a)) + a);
}

function Node(parentNode, numberOfVars,
               mode, weight, method, numberOfChildren, varIndex, value) {

  this.mode = mode ? mode : randint(0, 3);

  this.parent = parentNode;
  this.weight = weight ? weight : 1;

  if (this.mode == 0) { //constant
    this.value = value ? value : 1;
  } else if (this.mode == 1) { //variable
    this.varIndex = varIndex ? varIndex : randint(0, numberOfVars - 1);
  } else if (this.mode == 2) { //binary
    this.method = method ? method : Node.binary[randint(0, Node.binary.length - 1)];
  } else if (this.mode == 3) { //unary
    this.method = method ? method : Node.unary[randint(0, Node.unary.length - 1)];
  }

  if (numberOfChildren) {
    this.children = new Array(numberOfChildren);
  } else {
    this.children = [];

    if (this.mode == 2) { //binary
      this.children = [new Node(this, numberOfVars),
                       new Node(this, numberOfVars)
                      ];
    } else if (this.mode == 3) { //unary
      this.children = [new Node(this, numberOfVars)];
    }
  }

  //Methods
  this.execute = function(top_level_variables) {
    print("executing " + this.mode);
    var inputs = [];
    this.children.forEach(function(child, index) {
      print("child index " + index);
      inputs.push(child.execute(top_level_variables) * child.weight);
    });
    print("    inputs = " + inputs);

    if (this.mode == 0) {
      print("    mode == 0");
      return this.constant();
    }
    if (this.mode == 1) {
      print("    mode == 1");
      return this.variable(top_level_variables);
    }
    if (this.mode == 2) {
      print("    mode == 2");
      return this.method(inputs[0], inputs[1]);
    }
    if (this.mode == 3) {
      print("    mode == 3");
      return this.method(inputs[0]);
    }
  };
  var getIndent = function(indent) {
    var str = "";
    if (indent === 0)
      return str;

    for (var i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
      str += " | ";
    }
    return str;
  };
  this.getTree = function(indent) {
    if (this.mode == 0) {
      print(getIndent(indent) + "(" + this.value + ")");
    } else if (this.mode == 1) {
      print(getIndent(indent) + "x[" + this.varIndex + "]");
    } else if (this.mode == 2) {
      print(getIndent(indent) + this.method.name);
      this.children[0].getTree(indent + 1);
      this.children[1].getTree(indent + 1);
    } else if (this.mode == 3) {
      print(getIndent(indent) + this.method.name);
      this.children[0].getTree(indent + 1);
    }
  };
  this.getStr = function() {
    if (this.mode == 0) {
      return this.value;
    } else if (this.mode == 1) {
      return "x[" + this.varIndex + "]";
    } else if (this.mode == 2) {
      return this.method.name + "( " + this.children[0].getStr() + ", " + this.children[1].getStr() + " )";
    } else if (this.mode == 3) {
      return this.method.name + "( " + this.children[0].getStr() + " )";
    }
  };
}

Node.binary = [
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  },
  function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b
  },
  function power(a, b) {
    return Math.pow(a, b)
  }
];
Node.unary = [
  function sin(a) {
    return Math.sin(a)
  }
];
Node.prototype.constant = function() {
  return this.value
};
Node.prototype.variable = function(variables) {
  return variables[this.varIndex]
};

//Test
var a = new Node(null, 2, 2);
a.getTree(0);
print(a.getStr())
print(a.getDepth());
var b = a.execute([1, 3]);
print(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you try to generate random expression trees; pseudocode (somewhat Scala-inspired) for that might look something like this:

```
NVars = 2
def generateTree(level) = {
   if (level > 100) { generateVarref() }
   else {
     val choice = randomChoice(4)
     switch (choice) {
       case 0 => generateVarref()
       case 1 => generateConstant()
       case 2 => generateUnary(level + 1)
       case 3 => generateBinary(level + 1)
     }
   }
}
def generateVarref() = {
  val c = randomChoice(NVars)
  VarRef(c)
}
def generateConstant() = {
  Number(randomChoice(100))
}
def generateUnary(level) = {
  val c = randomChoice(6)
  val subexpr = generateTree(level)
  switch (c) {
    case 0 => Negate(subexpr)
    case 1 => Sin(subexpr)
    // etc. More unary functions here
  }
}
def generateBinary(level) = {
  val c = randomChoice(4)
  val sub1 = generateTree(level)
  val sub2 = generateTree(level)
  switch (c) {
    case 0 => Plus(sub1, sub2)
    case 1 => Minus(sub1, sub2)
    case 2 => Times(sub1, sub2)
    case 3 => Divide(sub1, sub2)
  }
}
```

Where `Plus`, `Varref`, etc are constructors for an expression type that implements a method that will then allow you to evaluate the expression at given values.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your functions have `2` variables `x1` and `x2` (if this assumption is too restrictive just adapt my answer to `n` variables `x1`, ..., `xn`.)

**[Start]** Generate random polynomial functions

This would entail

- modeling polynomials in `2` variables (`x1` and `x2`)
- implementing the evaluation of polynomials on (any) particular values of the variables
- generating random polynomial functions by taking a random degree (up to a certain max) and random coefficients (inside a given interval)

**[Compose]** Enable Function Composition

This would entail

- implementing the composition of functions so that if, say `f`, `g` and `h` are functions in your model (randomly generated or not), then `f(g,h)` is also a function in your model.

**[Enrich]** Add new function families to your model

Here you have to consider (and implement) other types of functions to the one you already have (polynomial): rational, trigonometric, logarithmic, exponential, etc. For every new type, you will have to model them and also, to implement a way of generating random instances of them (much as you did for the polynomials.)

**[Generate]** Create random functions combining all of the above

- Choose some types randomly
- For every type, generate a random instance
- Compose all the types into a final result.

**[Iterate]** Go to [Enrich] and add new types of functions

- Ditto.